# CSS - двойной Hover

Tags: html, css, hover

господа. 
Имею следующий код:

```css
.pre {}

.comf {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.pre p {
  width: 301px;
  height: 226px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 18px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50.4%;
  left: 50.0%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.pre p:hover,
img:hover+p {
  opacity: 1;
}

.pre .col-md-4>div {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="pre">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="comf">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/02/05/12/23/brick-258938_640.jpg">
      <p>Парампампам.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: ы]

То есть при наведении на картинку фон затемняется и появляется текст. 
Нужно сделать так, что бы в нижней части картинки уже был текст с короткой информацией, а при наведении на неё было так же, как в моем примере. Т.е. область с короткой информацией исчезает, картинка затемняется полностью и появляется текст с полной информацией.

Заранее извиняюсь, если подал текст не профессионально) Думаю суть вопроса донести смогу. Прожевал много информации, но ничего удачного не вышло к сожалению.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.picts {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.pict {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.pict img {
  display: block;
}

.pict:before,
.pict-caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s linear;
}

.pict:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.pict-caption {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
}

.pict:hover:before,
.pict:hover .pict-caption {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="picts">
  <div class="pict">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250" alt="">
    <div class="pict-caption">
      CSS - двойной Hover
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pict">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250" alt="">
    <div class="pict-caption">
      CSS - двойной Hover
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Только немного по-другому хотелось бы. Нужно сделать так, что бы без наведения на картинку, снизу к примеру на 20 пикселей всегда был ховер с краткой информацией, а при наведении краткая информация исчезает и появляется полное описание услуги.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно один блок скрывать сразу.

При наведении один блок скрываем, а другой отображаем.

```
.posle {
    display:none;
}
.wrap:hover .posle {
    display:block;
}
.wrap:hover .do {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Будем пытаться)